# How to check table count and use it in an if-statement in swift iOS

Tags: swift, database, sqlite

I'm trying to do a check in my database, I want to make sure that there is only one entry (row) in my database and only use that row and must not add any additional entry (row).

```
if self.heroTable.count >= 1 {
    let setHeroLevelandExpi = self.heroTable.insert(self.level <- 1, self.expi <- 25, self.maxExpi <- 30)
}
```

But it says that "Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ScalarQuery<Int>' and 'Int'". Am I missing anything?

Comment: What is `heroTable`? What SQLite library are you using? But why both checking the count? Perform an "INSERT OR REPLACE" query instead of a simple "INSERT". Of course that requires a unique key.

Comment: I'm using this layer of SQLite (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) if it helps. the heroTable was created via `let heroTable = Table("hero")` is this information correct for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the library, you actually need to run the count query.

```
if let rowCount = try? db.scalar(heroTable.count) as? Int64, rowCount >= 1 {
    // there are 1 or more rows in the table
}
```

Comment: This one works to me, just checking some changes, can I ask how do you get individual values from this database like level and put it to variable?

Comment: That's a whole different question but I'd start by reading the documentation for the library you are using and the sample shown on the project site.